# Странная проблема с Chrome в Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, видеокарта

Купил ноут Xiaomi, там установлена ОС Windows 10. При изменении размера окна браузера Chrome появляется черный след, который пропадает, когда размер зафиксирован. В других программах такого не замечал. Хотел сделать скринкаст с помощью OBS, но OBS не хочет работать, что тоже странно.

Подскажите, как исправить или хотя бы понять в чем проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Драйвера на видео установлены последние с оф. сайта?

Comment: Изначально драйвера уже стояли, я это проверил путем нажатия на иконку Nvidia в углу, открылись настройки и там были данные о карте. Тогда это проблема уже была. Я решил переустановить ос, поставил windows 10 pro, драйвера на карту кажется сами установились, так же появился значок Nvidia. Но я решил вручную их установить, зайдя в на оф сайт, но не смог этого сделать, писалось что-то вроде драйвера не соответствуют карте. Погуглив я наткнулся на инфу, что у ноутов xiomi какая то урезанная карта и дрова можно стаивть только с их оф сайта, то есть с сайта xiaomi.

Answer (score 0):

Такая же хрень стала после обновления форточки до 18363, также иногда странно открывается центр обновлений: анимация не справа налево, а полностью появляется окно под него, а затем быстро слева направо открывается панель. Либо дрова на видео, либо форточка гонит

Comment: получилось исправить или не стали заморачиваться ?

Comment: нет не заморачиваюсь, только в хроме такое наблюдается, остальные окна ресайзятся нормально, у меня дэсктоп, так что это не только на нотниках, хотя сейчас перепроверил на surface book 2 та же хрень, на планшете  surface тоже. Что-то с хромом не то.